# Build Error in Dart / Flutter during build

Tags: firebase, dart, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

So in my build function, I load my user data, and once it is loaded I would like to change the theme of the app (which calls setState()). The issue is that I can't call setState during the build process, like the error below states. How would I go about loading a user selected theme on app startup? Also, is it not recommended to be loading data inside the build function? It seems to work well but feels kinda gross. Thanks!

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //get user object from Firebase
    //once user is loaded, take their chosen color theme and call updateTheme()
}
```

Error:

```
This ThemeSwitcherWidget widget cannot be marked as needing to build because the framework is
I/flutter (23889): already in the process of building widgets. A widget can be marked as needing to be built during the
I/flutter (23889): build phase only if one of its ancestors is currently building. This exception is allowed because
I/flutter (23889): the framework builds parent widgets before children, which means a dirty descendant will always be
```

Comment: Do not call `setState()` in `build()`. You'd need to post more code for better suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

For loading data or doing a blocking call, you should use [FutureBuilder](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) or [StreamBuilder](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/StreamBuilder-class.html) (I am not much aware of firebase APIs so can't tell which one to use, but both of them are very similar.) It takes a future or stream as an argument and builds based on it. I am assuming you know about future API of dart

Here is some example code that will give you some idea.

```
StreamBuilder<FirebaseUser>(
  stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.onAuthStateChanged,
  builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
      return new SplashScreen();
    } else {
      if (snapshot.hasData) {
        return new MainScreen(firestore: firestore, uuid: snapshot.data.uid);
      }
      return new LoginScreen();
    }
  }
)
```